# code jam practice-- reading problem

Tags: c, file-io

I refer to code jam because most of you will understand the kind of input file we have.
the problem is - qualification 2010 (snapper)

The problem I'm facing in my program that it reads the first input of `100005` as `10000 5` as separately two integers thus changing the entire input to the program. Here's my code for reading the input:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *op=fopen("20101op.txt","w");
    FILE *ip=fopen("A-small-practice.in","rt");

    long int  i,N,K,c;
    fscanf(ip,"%ld ",&c);

    printf("%d \t", c);
    fscanf(ip,"%ld ",&N);
    printf("%d \t", N);
    fscanf(ip,"%ld ",&K);
    printf("%d \t", K);

    fclose(op);
    fclose(ip);

    return 0;
}
```

Please help me find out the cause of this problem!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your compiler is trying to prevent an overflow by limiting fscanf to 16-bits.

What compiler (and version), and what operating system are you using?  32 or 64 bit?

Also, what does fscanf return?

(Test this by changing this line:

```
fscanf(ip,"%ld ",&c);
```

to these lines:)

```
int rv;
rv = fscanf(ip,"%ld ",&c);
printf("fscanf() returned: %d\n", rv);
```

Note: I can't comment on the above response (not enough reputation), but the 't' is used in some compilers to explicitly specify that the file is a **text** file.

**Update**:
This function should parse longs character-by-character.  See my comment about using this.

```
int fparselong(FILE * fp, long * ip)
{
    int parsed = 0;
    *ip = 0;
    int c;
    while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        // c is newline, return 0 if nothing has been parsed, 1 if something has
        if(c == '\n'){ return parsed; }
        // check for oob
        if(c < '0' || c > '9'){ return -1; }
        // Update ip
        *ip = *ip * 10 + (c - '0');
        // Something has been parsed
        parsed = 1;
    }
    // EOF received
    return -2;
}
```

So rather than:

```
fscanf(ip,"%ld ",&c);
```

You'd have:

```
fparselong(ip, &c);
```

Again, if this works, don't use it, but find another compiler.  If it doesn't, it suggests an unexpected character appears in your file.  You could [hexdump](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_hexdump.htm) your input file or use some other means of determining this.

Comment: +1 for noticing the 16-bit limit :) Oh .. and welcome to Stack Overflow

Comment: i am using code block 10.05 on win 7 64 bit
fscanf() returns 1

Comment: Code Block is your IDE, what compiler are you using?  Microsoft Visual C++, MingW, GCC,etc.?

Comment: I added a function that should parse longs character-by-character to my answer.  This should not be used in production, see if your compiler is deficient.  If this code works, you should really consider switching compilers.

Comment: there is an interesting situation which i face now.. If i retype the numbers in the source file i downloaded from the code jam site i get the correct results  :(

Comment: My guess is that you have some weird character in your data file -- you sould check with something like Notepad++

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the return values of **ALL** input library functions (`fopen`, `fscanf`).

Also, there's an invalid character (the `'t'`) in the mode argument of the 2nd fopen.

Comment: The 't' is used in some compilers to explicitly specify that the file is a **text** file. -- [jedwards](http://stackoverflow.com/users/736937/jedwards)

Comment: @jedwards: ok, but the absence of `'b'` makes it a text stream. Why repeat the information with a redundant character? And more importantly: why write code that is not portable for no significant gain whatsoever? ??

Comment: (Yay, I can comment everywhere now!) @pmg, I completely agree, I see no real need for 't' other than to confuse and (once you find out what it is for) annoy.

Comment: Ah! Annoyances ... one more for my bag: `void main`, cast the return value of `malloc()`, `char ch = getchar();`, `for (i=1; i<=10; i++)`, ... and use `'t'` in `fopen()` mode :)